# How to update a column based on multiple string of another column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table with two strings in a column. I am trying to update the multicode column based on the EN in Lookup table. Below are the tables:

#Lookup table

| EN | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Annual meadow grass | 45 |
| Growth regulation | 828 |
| Leaf scald | 971 |
| Weeds - Broadleaf | 1997 |

#Table that must be updated

| ResponseCode | EN | Multicode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6d5j87 | Annual meadow grass,Weeds - Broadleaf | NULL |
| 6d5j87 | Growth regulation, Leaf scald | NULL |
| 6d5j87 | Leaf scald, Weeds - Broadleaf | NULL |

#Expected Table output

| ResponseCode | EN | Multicode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6d5j87 | Annual meadow grass,Weeds - Broadleaf | 45,1997 |
| 6d5j87 | Growth regulation | 828 |
| 6d5j87 | Leaf scald, Weeds - Broadleaf | 971,1997 |

Current code:

```
select EN, ID From #TargetFlatten1
select ResponseCode, EN, Multicode From #targettest
```

Comment: Your design seems to have some normalization issues. You should not store the string value in multiple tables. That is the point of a relational database. You store one and only one value for those strings. Then you store the key value in your other tables as a foreign key. And last but not least, your desired table violates 1NF by storing multiple values in a single tuple.

Comment: Fixing your design is your priority here. You need a many to many relationship, with foreign key constraints, not a delimited split with no validation on it (because it can't be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option turns the CSV string to rows with [`string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), does the lookup, then aggregates back the codes with [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
select t.responseCode, t.en, x.multicode
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select string_agg(l.responseCode) within group (order by ordinal) as multicode
    from string_split(t.en, ',', 1)
    inner join mylookup l on l.en = value
) x
```

`value` and `ordinal` are two columns generated by `string_split` wich store (resp) the single value and its original position in the CSV list.

If you wanted an update, we can turn the logic to a correlated subquery:

```
update t
set t.multicode = (
    select string_agg(l.responseCode) within group (order by ordinal)
    from string_split(t.en, ',', 1)
    inner join mylookup l on l.en = value
)
from mytable t
```

Comment: If the OP responds with "Unrecognised function 'STRING_AGG'" I'll headdesk... Lol

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using `STRING_SPLIT` with param 1 to enable ordinal  (sql server 2022 ):

```
SELECT t2.ResponseCode, t2.EN, string_agg(ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ordinal ) 
FROM table2 t2
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t2.EN, ',', 1) AS s
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 on t1.EN = TRIM(s.value)
GROUP BY t2.ResponseCode, t2.EN
```

The update statement can be :

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Multicode = s.Multicode
FROM table2 t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t2.ResponseCode, t2.EN, string_agg(ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ordinal ) AS Multicode 
  FROM table2 t2
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t2.EN, ',', 1) AS s
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1 on t1.EN = TRIM(s.value)
  GROUP BY t2.ResponseCode, t2.EN
) AS S on s.ResponseCode = t.ResponseCode and s.EN = t.EN
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/pH0H7cEX)

For **SQL SERVER 2017 & 2019** we can use `OPENJSON` to preserve ordinal :

```
SELECT t2.ResponseCode, t2.EN, string_agg(ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY [key] ) AS Multicode
FROM table2 t2
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' +  REPLACE(t2.EN,',','","') + '"]') AS s
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 on t1.EN = TRIM(s.value)
GROUP BY t2.ResponseCode, t2.EN
```

Update statement :

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Multicode = s.Multicode
FROM table2 t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t2.ResponseCode, t2.EN, string_agg(ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY [key] ) AS Multicode 
  FROM table2 t2
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' +  REPLACE(t2.EN,',','","') + '"]') AS s
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1 on t1.EN = TRIM(s.value)
  GROUP BY t2.ResponseCode, t2.EN
) AS S on s.ResponseCode = t.ResponseCode and s.EN = t.EN
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GolzT3zA)

Comment: hi, i am using sql server 2018 and it says Procedure or function STRING_SPLIT has too many arguments specified.

Comment: I see, Are you interested by the order of ids on Multicode ?

Comment: Yes, and also i have updated my table. There also a column with only 1 EN

Comment: There is no "SQL Server 2018"... There were releases in 2017 and 2019, but not in 2018. You can't be using the version you state @Sriram . Your update doesn't make sense for a "2018 version" either, SelVazi, because no such version exists.

Comment: Thanks @ThomA for the correction .. I  missed this .. thanks again

Comment: @ThomA sorry, my bad. It was SSMS v18.9.2

Comment: That's the version of SSMS, not the version of SQL Server, @Sriram. SSMS 18 supports SQL Server 2008-2019; that's *seven* different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are stuck with such a terrible schema, and assuming your data does have spaces in odd places like your example, and assuming you don't have any lookup values with comma's in them ... this should work in ms sql server - don't ask me about other flavors :)

```
select 
  m.response_code
  ,m.en
  ,string_agg(l.id, ',') multicode
from 
  multicodes m
left join
  lookup l on l.en in (select trim(value) from string_split(m.en, ','))
group by
  m.response_code
  ,m.en
```